# SimpleJson Deserialize<T> Failing when indexing added

Tags: c#, .net, restsharp

I have a downloaded string, cut short to reduce length on this service, that is in proper JSON format:

```
{"expand":"schema,names","startAt":0,"maxResults":50,"total":4,"issues":[{"expand":"operations,versionedRepresentations,editmeta,changelog,renderedFields","id":"RNG-Key","self":"https://myJira.atlassian.net/rest/api/2/issue/RNG-Key","key":"RNG-Key","fields":{"customfield_17024":null,"customfield_17023":null,"customfield_10073":null,"customfield_17022":null,"customfield_14311":null,"customfield_12010":null,"customfield_14312":null,"customfield_14310":null,"customfield_14315":null}}]}
```

When deserializing using Restsharp.SimpleJson.SimpleJson.Deserialize() there are no issues with the returned value. When I add indexing to the 'fields' portion of the class, it fails for argument exception. The Indexing code is below:

```
public object this[string propertyName]
{
     get
    {
        return typeof(Fields).GetProperty(propertyName).GetValue(this, null);
    }
    set
    {
        typeof(Fields).GetProperty(propertyName).SetValue(this, value, null);
    }
}
```

> ArgumentException was unahandled: Incorrect number of arguments supplied for call to method 'Void set_Item(System.String, System.Object)'

I utilize the indexing later in the code and would like to be able to keep this in place, but for now it doesn't appear it is going to work. For ease of working, I have added the classes below with the indexer in place.

```
public class Fields
{
    public object this[string propertyName]
    {
        get
        {
            return typeof(Fields).GetProperty(propertyName).GetValue(this, null);
        }
        set
        {
            typeof(Fields).GetProperty(propertyName).SetValue(this, value, null);
        }
    }
    public object customfield_17024 { get; set; }
    public object customfield_17023 { get; set; }
    public object customfield_10073 { get; set; }
    public object customfield_17022 { get; set; }
    public object customfield_14311 { get; set; }
    public object customfield_12010 { get; set; }
    public object customfield_14312 { get; set; }
    public object customfield_14310 { get; set; }
    public object customfield_14315 { get; set; }
}

public class Issue
{
    public string expand { get; set; }
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string self { get; set; }
    public string key { get; set; }
    public Fields fields { get; set; }
}

public class SearchResults
{
    public string expand { get; set; }
    public int startAt { get; set; }
    public int maxResults { get; set; }
    public int total { get; set; }
    public List<Issue> issues { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Either try to ignore the index as part of the serialization, or check if the property really exists. Any chance you could identify which setter failed? Do you really need an indexer? Couldn't an extensions method with get & set property from a given object work? Or can't you use a dictionary for your fields?

Comment: Unfortunately indexing is used heavily elsewhere in the program. I have tried adding [JsonIgnore], although this seems to do little when deserializing. I have no data as to which setter is failing, although I could likely load individual pieces and narrow it down, I was hoping this wasn't a single point problem. I have used the same method for indexing for quite some time and this is the first time running into issues, and would prefer not changing everything based on a single failure if it can be fixed.

Comment: Do you have to use `SimpleJson`?

Comment: As far as I read the documentation, you could implement your `Fields` as a `Dictionary` for the property, that would keep the indexing or from the source code I saw that it only write to properties that have `CanWrite` as true, so you could remove the setter from your indexing

Comment: @DavidG I suppose adding a new using and switching to a different deserializer that doesn't crash on this would fix the issue. I have tried with newtonsoft after your suggestion and it appears to function with the indexer in place.

Comment: What happens if you use the 2 argument overload of `SetValue` instead? Have you tried that instead of 3 arguments?

Comment: @CodingYoshi changing to the 2 argument overload for `SetValue` doesn't appear to change anything as far as the failure goes.